# Android - too large array causes outofmemory error

Tags: android, arrays, performance, out-of-memory

So in my Android application, the first thing that initializes are the `Tile` objects that is going to be used in my Astar pathfinding. The `Tile` object is a class that holds x-y-coordinates, G- and H-cost for the tile. The application is initializing tiles for every floor (meaning another map) I have optimized the Astar so it generates total of 6000 tiles per floor (a floor is 800x800) and I have to initialize all floors before making a path searching with Astar because the user can travel from e.g floor 1 to floor 2. So the tiles have to be "ready" to be used. It can initialize 3 floors in total, then the user is not able to do anything more because the application will crash because of outofmemory.

The `Tile` objects are created and stored into an 3-dimensional array of `Tile`, thus; `Tile[FLOORS][HEIGHT][WIDTH]`. The problem is that my map is really big which makes this array big too. The first thing that I was thinking about was to use database to store all the tiles but the problem is that it would be inefficient to go through every tile when the Astar algorithm is trying to find a path form point A to B considering all the query injections. <-- I am still wondering if there is a faster way that I haven't figured out yet (with database).

I have literally searched through whole StackOverFlow but haven't found any solution to my problem. Others have been told to use database because their arrays are getting too large but in my case, the tiles have to be structured as `Tile[floor][y][x]` in order to access them really fast.

So is there any way to store all the tiles into an array, free them from the memory but in a way reuse them when needed?

Comment: Are you using actual Java objects for your tiles, why? What about a three dimensional byte array or something? Maybe even in combination with a hashmap for quick lookup? Also is there a reason to even load other floors in the first place? Why not load it once it needs to be used?

Comment: Oh, could you give me some examples of how to use hash map? (In my case with tiles) Also, they have to be loaded before because the system needs to know the connections between the tiles so it finds the shortest path